# reCAPTCHA API Key Pair = "Site Key" or "Secret Key"

Tags: form

I was looking to add reCAPTCHA to a "Web-to-Lead" form in salesforce. (Setup>Feature Settings>Marketing>Web-to-Lead) As part of the setup salesforce asks that you "Enter the API key pair you got when you registered your site with Google". When you register with google you are given two keys. I was wondering if anyone had figured out if it is the Site key or the Secret Key that salesforce is looking for here or maybe both

[image: Salesforce Web to Form Error]

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on your question.

Comment: Yes, I was looking to add reCAPTCHA to a "Web-to-Lead" form in salesforce.  (Setup>Feature Settings>Marketing>Web-to-Lead)  As part of the setup salesforce asks that you "Enter the API key pair you got when you registered your site with Google".  When you register with google you are given two keys. I was wondering if anyone had figured out if it is the Site key or the Secret Key that salesforce is looking for here or maybe both?

Answer (score 0):

you have to put both, click on the lookup button(magnifying glass right side), in the new window click New to put the keys.